# How to transfer in single player mode in Fifa 14

Tags: fifa-14

This is driving me nuts. I'm new to Fifa as a whole so go easy on me.

I'm playing offline in single player mode on Fifa 14 (PC) as a player. I've been "on loan from Barcelona B" playing for some awful team for what seems like 100 matches.

When transfer time comes, I have no idea how to transfer. All it gives me is an advance button and 8 hours of time to advance through. I see a bunch of teams with what looks like players being transferred, and money spent on those players, but I'm never transferred.

What gives?

Comment: Should hand in a transfer request.

Comment: @loko Where do I go to do that? I've gone through every possible menu but can't seem to find anything related to transferring.

Comment: Euhm I'll check soon wait.

Comment: I had a similar question. Do I automatically get clubs to transfer to as options (like in other Fifas), or do I need to put in a transfer request before the end of the season? Also, Barca B are the reserve team for Barca, but they play in Spain's second division. They don't have a reserve league there. They aren't allowed to play in the same league as Barca and there are restrictions on player mobility, so it's basically a different team to Barca.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on loan. You can hand in a transfer request once you're back at the normal club. You can't be transferred while being on loan.

**How to transfer:**

My Pro -> My Actions

Comment: Ohhh I see. How long is it usually before you are back on your home team? Or is it random?

Comment: @Moses Normally it's just one season al though I have no idea where barcelona b plays and till where the season is ending.

Comment: @Moses No problem. Also when you just start a pro career at a big club. (I am assuming your normal club is Barcelona?) You should definitly go on a loan or else you wont get playing time

Comment: My Actions only seems to show: Withdraw Loan Request (I didn't request to go on loan) .. and retire. I'm stuck with the club that hates me! :)

Comment: @peteski22 Withdraw Loan Request does mean you have asked for a loan request though. Or the club might have put you on the loan list maybe. Any club from ireland or whatever will pick you up.